# Why is this variable not defined when I defined it globally? (javascript, p5.js)

Tags: javascript, p5.js

I'm using JS to fetch a JSON and the p5.js library (source below) to draw a canvas and a dot based on the data therein. The `ellipse()` function needs to get the variable `position`, but that variable is only accessible from where the console.log("position inside function") is, and not globally.

[image: the variable "position" is accessible from where the console.log("position inside function") is, and not globally]

My code is the following:

```js
function setup() {
  createCanvas(400, 400);
}
var position;
function draw() {
  var promise = fetch("http://api.open-notify.org/iss-now.json");
  
  background(20, 29, 22);
  promise.then(response => {
    if (response.status !== 200) {
      console.log('Looks like there was a problem. Status Code: ' +
        response.status);
      return;
    }
    response.json().then(data => {
      window.position = data;
    })
    .catch(error => {
      console.log(error.message);
    })
    console.log("position inside function");
    setTimeout(function(){
      if(position.iss_position.longitude && position.iss_position.latitude)
      console.log("longitude" + position.iss_position.longitude);
      console.log("latitude" + position.iss_position.latitude);
    },500);
  })
  translate(180, 180);
  ellipse(parseFloat(window.position.iss_position.longitude), parseFloat(window.position.iss_position.latitude), 4, 4);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://github.com/processing/p5.js/releases/download/1.1.9/p5.min.js"></script>
```

I've read different sources about global variables in JS and tried different combinations of `window.position` instead of `position` in the variable declaration, tried declaring it without `var` and declaring it in the setup() function. Nothing worked so far. I am a bit of a JS noob, and I think is a very basic factor I'm ignoring.

Comment: You might want to have a look at [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6mT3r8Qn1VY&list=PLRqwX-V7Uu6a-SQiI4RtIwuOrLJGnel0r&index=4) which shows exactly what you want to do. The idea is to use p5js [`loadJSON()`](https://p5js.org/reference/#/p5/loadJSON) function which will offload the work of using promises. As the doc says you could also call `loadJSON` from [`preload()`](https://p5js.org/reference/#/p5/preload) to make things even easier.

Comment: This was perfect! Shiffman was querying the same API, awesome, this solved my issues

Comment: When you want to do something with processing this guy often has a very related video on his channel it’s usually worth to have a look :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to put those lines

```
translate(180, 180);
ellipse(parseFloat(window.position.iss_position.longitude), parseFloat(window.position.iss_position.latitude), 4, 4);
```

inside your response.then().

The promise is working asynchronous and the variable value is probably not set when you are calling the function outside the promise.

Comment: makes sense, right? AndI tried this, but for some reason the ellipse() function seems to be quite buggy when I call it from inside there instead of in the outer shell of the scope of draw()

Comment: what do you mean with "quite buggy" ? Since I dont know when you want to call the functions, I can't really help you out. Why are you trying to call them after the promise when you can just use them inside?

Comment: The fact is, the service that I'm querying can be choppy when the endpoint is queried too frequently. I resolved to lowering the frame rate quite a lot (`frameRate(1)` in the `setup()` function )  and now it works like charm.

Comment: In the end, specifying a low frameRate() (1 in my case) did the trick, but a better way would have been to wrap the request in a setTimer() function without limiting the frame rate.